# importing putty connections from old registry- load hive disabled

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, bsod, putty

How do I import putty connections from an old registry? The old hard drive is USB connected.
The option "load hive" is disabled in Regedit.
What are my options?
Operating system:Windows Seven
I got a new HD and installed WIN7 on the new one. The old HD(had WIn7 installed) boots to BSOD. Blue screen of death. The old HD is with me for limited time, so what files related to putty do I need to copy to the new HD?

THanks

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157.aspx) `Load Hive...` is only enabled when `HKEY_USERS` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is selected. Once you have loaded the old hive you can locate the PuTTY settings and export them (and import them again after fixing the key names in the exported file).

Usually you don't have to copy anything else to have PuTTY work as before. If you've created any keys (with Pageant) you might want to copy these to your new disk.

Comment: that was the first thing I checked. It remains greyed even after after HKEY_CURRENT_USER is selected.

Comment: Oops my mistake (can't even copy text) That should have been HKEY_USERS. Edited.

Comment: the only file I backed up from my old HD is ntuser.dat. Is that sufficient? A new dialog box asks for a key.?

Comment: Yes, the old hive will be shown with the key you specify in that dialog box. If you're done with it you can (should) unload it again by selecting that key and doing "Unload Hive..." from the menu. If your ntuser.dat is from the user that had the putty settings it's the file you need.

Comment: THere is only "Microsoft" under software, no Simontatham.

Comment: Does the rest of the contents indicate that it's the right file?

Comment: It is THE file. But that's the only file from old HD.

Comment: If it's the only file you have and it doesn't have the settings you need, you're probably out of luck. Sorry.